# Google sheets: swap column value if present

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps

How can I write a formula in Google sheets to swap a value between `Column 1` and `Column 2` only if there's a value in `Column 2`?

```
    1    |    2
-------------------
    V    |
    S    |    T
```

I want the second row to swap, not the first. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty easy. Here's the formula for the first column:

```
=if(B2, B2, A2)
```